# Currying in python

Tags: python-3.x, currying

I wrote the following function

```
def addsub(a): 
     def add(a): 
         def subtract(b): 
             return a-b 
         return subtract 
     return add(a)
```

addsub(9)(4)
returns 5

but what if I do not know to number of add subtract I want to perform
addsub(9)(3)(4)(5).

The above function does not work for it
could I write something general which works for any length of input?

PS. I do not want to use functools

Comment: I don't think it's possible in this form. If `addsub(9)(4)` returns `5`, `addsub(9)(4)(3)` will fail, because `5(3)` cannot be called.

Comment: What do you expect the result of `addsub(9)(3)(4)(5)` to be and why? (Do you want to subtract all numbers after the first?)

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Thanks a lot. I am so sorry for not replying for such a long time. I was not informed about the update. As a result of ```addsub(9)(3)(4)(5)```, I want 9-3+4-5.

Comment: @bereal Yeah, it will fail. I want to know how could I modify my code so that I can implement the alternate sum subtract of any sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible exactly like you describe (with currying). But if all you want is to sum the numbers of a list with a varying sign, this looks the most straightforward to me:

```
import itertools
coefficients = itertools.cycle((1, -1))
numbers = [9, 3, 4, 5]
result = sum(a * c for a, c in zip(numbers, coefficients))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That really does the trick.